# How to interpret ArUco's output

Tags: linux, vision, aruco

I am new with ArUco, and I am having some problems trying to understands the units in the output like this:

817=(527.126,235.966) (525.665,210.056) (552.459,208.619) (553.243,234.68) Txyz=0.155419 -0.0140956 0.56691 Rxyz=-1.53672 0.11339 0.0339042 
Time detection=4.93583 milliseconds

I understand that the first number (817) is the mark code, the first 4 brackets are the position of the corners, and the rest of the values are the Translation and Rotation. But what are the units of them?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Before posting any more questions, please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Thanks and Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The translation vector values are in meters and the rotation vectors are in radiands. Hope this helps